# For loop that wastes a lot of memory, change to mapply?

Tags: r, loops, leaflet, mapply

I have a very big dataset that I want to plot into leaflet, but I am using a "for loop" that takes very long. I have been told that It would be faster using a mapply function but I don't know how to convert my for loop into mapply.

My final purpose is having my code going quicker.

Look I have this example of my dataset and of the map result:

```
#import libraries:

library(data.table)
library(leaflet) 

#dataset:


lat<-c(40.41766, 40.43305 ,40.43687, 40.39563, 40.39088, 40.39215, 40.39458, 40.40451, 40.40627, 40.40864)

lng<-c(-3.701328, -3.709352, -3.708531, -3.736556, -3.734796, -3.741867, -3.741222, -3.705399, -3.710980, -3.710310)

colors<-c("#3D00FFFF","#52FF00FF","#3D00FFFF","#0052FFFF","#52FF00FF","#52FF00FF","#52FF00FF","#0052FFFF","#3D00FFFF","#0052FFFF")

name<-c("Rafa","Luis","Rafa","Belen","Luis","Luis","Luis","Belen","Rafa","Belen")

hour_range<-c("Sleeping_Hours","Morning_rush_hours","Morning_Working_Hours","Sleeping_Hours","Morning_rush_hours","Morning_Working_Hours","Sleeping_Hours","Morning_rush_hours","Morning_Working_Hours","Morning_Working_Hours")

data<- data.table(name,lat,lng,hour_range,colors)

#As you can see the data.table has 5 variables (name, lat, lng, hour_range,colors)

#My objective is to plot in leaflet a line of every person (name)in a 
#different color and also with 1 layer for each hour_range).

#I was able to do so with a for loop:

map<-  leaflet(data)
map<- addTiles(map)

for( name in unique(data$name)){ 
  map<- addPolylines(map, lng=~lng,lat=~lat,data=data[data$name==name & data$hour_range=="Sleeping_Hours",], group= "Sleeping_Hours",color=~colors)
  map<- addPolylines(map, lng=~lng,lat=~lat,data=data[data$name==name & data$hour_range=="Morning_rush_hours",], group= "Morning_rush_hours",color=~colors)
  map<- addPolylines(map, lng=~lng,lat=~lat,data=data[data$name==name & data$hour_range=="Morning_Working_Hours",], group= "Morning_Working_Hours",color=~colors)


}
map<-addLayersControl(map=map,
                             overlayGroups=c("Sleeping_Hours","Morning_rush_hours","Morning_Working_Hours"),
                             options=layersControlOptions(collapsed=FALSE)

map
```

This map works fine because it is a small dataset but with a longer one does not work, how could I make it work faster? how could I apply here a mapply function instead of a loop?

Thanks !

Comment: I'm not convinced that switching to an `apply`-based approach will result in faster computation. And even if it does, it might produce memory problems with big data as the whole operation (all loops together) need to fit in your RAM.

Comment: I think the same, as the main bottleneck is gonna be leaflet and the layer creation..

Comment: Maybe `mapview` would be a faster alternative/addition to leaflet?

Comment: Thanks SeGa and LAP. I changed polylines to circlemarkers and It works faster, I will also try mapview ! Thanks !